# Can we use the worklights center's appcenter to distribute pure nativeapps?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

We have developed Android Pure native application (using android java api), ios pure native application using objective c with xcode, 
We have worklight server installed in one of our server.
Can we use the worklight's application center to to distibute our pure native apps which are not developed using hybrid methodology, with our remote teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result for either a Worklight-based or fully native apps is the same - an .apk or .ipa... so it doesn't matter.

Simply deploy/upload the .apk or .ipa via the Application Center as you would for for a Worklight-based.

From the IBM Worklight user documentation: [Publishing Worklight applications to the Application Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/t_publishing_worklight_applicati.html)